# Does LXDE come with some default program similar to `xscreensaver` or `gnome-screensaver`?

Tags: lock-screen, lxde

Does LXDE come with some default program similar to `xscreensaver` or `gnome-screensaver`?

`light-locker` seems to be a program only for configuring when to start screen locking. Is it also the actual program which locks a screen?

Thanks.